# Seeking Suggestions for Improving Data Structures and Algorithm Implementation Using Stack

Tags: algorithm, c, pointers, loops

I need your thoughts and comments to at least improve my programming skills. For those who didn't know, I'm new at coding in C so some conventions in this language were new to me due to the fact that I got introduce to high-level languages such as Python and Java first. Suggestions and criticisms are highly appreciated.

The code below is about stacks from Data Structure and Algorithms, and I wrote this code to better understand how the algorithm works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAXSIZE 5

int y = 5;
int z = 10;
struct stack
{
    int a[MAXSIZE];
    int Top;
};

void push(struct stack *pU)
{
    int size;
    const int x = 4; // Each element is 4 bytes 

    pU->Top = -1;
    size = sizeof(pU->a[pU->Top]) / x;

    if(size > MAXSIZE)
    {
        printf("stack is full\n");
        exit(2);
    } else {
    /*
     * First Element
     */
        pU->a[++pU->Top] = y;
        printf("Top element: %d\n", pU->a[pU->Top]);

    /*
     * Second Element
     */
    pU->a[++pU->Top] = z;
    printf("New top element: %d\n", pU->a[pU->Top]);
    }

    /*
     * Count index of array 
     */
    for(int i = -1; i <= pU->Top; ++i)
    {
        if(pU->a[i] >= 0 && pU->a[i] <= 99)
    {
        size = size + 1;

        if(size > MAXSIZE)
        {
                printf("Stack is full\n");
            exit(2);
        } else if(size == size){
            printf("Number of elements in array: %d\n", size);
        }
    }
    break;
    }

}

void pop(struct stack *pO)
{
    int size;
    const int x = 4;

    for(int i = 0; i < 1; ++i)
    {
         pO->Top = pO->Top - 1;  // Decrement Top
     printf("Recently added stack removed. Current stack is: %d\n", pO->a[pO->Top]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    struct stack *M;
    
    push(M);
    pop(M);
}
```

Comment: If you are using a “p” prefix to denote a Pointer, then please stop using Hungarian notation, it’s not a good fit here. If you’re writing code that others will read, then please don’t use {U, O, M}, as they are uninformative.

Comment: Thanks, what can you suggest for proper naming of notations?

Comment: @J_H See [Joel Spolsky on Apps Hungarian versus Systems Hungarian.](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2005/05/11/making-wrong-code-look-wrong/)

Comment: A great follow-up to this would be a stack implemented as a vector, which can grow by calling `realloc()`.

Comment: @Mingming187, I suggest you write code for humans to read, not for the machine to read. Figure out what the relevant concept is, and the name of the concept, and then use that name (or some legible abbreviation). For example, your identifier `size` was perfect (though using signed int was a curious choice, rather than `ssize_t` which is unsigned). Sometimes a single character name for local variable is great, e.g. a `for (i ...` loop. When you are defining a Public API that caller must learn about and understand, think twice before using a single-character name there.